# How to change number of displayed rows on devexpress gridview?

Tags: winforms, gridview, devexpress

I want to display only a row on my gridview. How to change, from designer or c#, the number of rows to be shown in a gridview?

Comment: How are you determining which row is the visible one? If there are multiple records, do you want to display only one but allow users to scroll to view others? Is there a filter you can apply to limit the data shown?

Answer (score -1):

If you only want to show a single row, you can hide them individually, or loop over the DataGrid and hide all of them except a specific row.

```
DataGridView.Rows[0].Visible = false;
```

Comment: Your solution pertains to the standard WinForms DataGridView. The DevExpress GridView as mentioned by the OP does not contain a Rows collection.